# Can't get mysqli identifier from another class

Tags: class, mysqli, identifier

I have two classes: one for sql and one for authentication. These are separate files that only "come together" by an autoloader in another file (index.php). The sql class looks like this:

```
class aF_sql {
    public static $open;
    public static $char;
    public static $close;

    public static function open() {
        global $config;

        self::$open = mysqli_connect($config['aF_sql_host'], $config['aF_sql_user'], $config['aF_sql_pass'], $config['aF_sql_data']);
        if(!self::$open) {
            die('<b>ERROR (/core/sql/1): Could not initialize database connection</b>');
        }

        self::$char = mysqli_set_charset(self::$open, $config['aF_sql_char']);
        if(!self::$char) {
            die('<br>ERROR (/core/sql/2): Could not set database charset</br>');
        }

        return TRUE;
    }

    public static function close() {
        self::$close = mysqli_close(self::$open);
        if(!self::$close) {
            die('<b>ERROR (/core/sql/3): Could not close database connection');
        }

        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Everything works fine until here. I open the sql connection by using the class::open(); method and I close it by using class::close();. Then, I have a file that should help me check some login details (the auth class). For now, all I want is an echo of the submitted username. Here is the content:

```
class aF_auth {
    public static function login() {
        echo mysqli_real_escape_string(aF_sql::open, $_POST['username']);
    }
}
```

Thisis what the error says: Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given... What should I use as an identifier to be able to perform queries? As you know, mysqli requires the connection identifier.

Thanks a million

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out! Instead of returning TRUE in the class, I return self::$open. This way, I can use aF_sql::$open everywhere in the software and it refers to the connection identifier. With other words, it didn't work because I was not returning the variable in the class...

```
class aF_sql {
public static $open;
public static $char;
public static $close;

public static function open() {
    global $config;

    self::$open = mysqli_connect($config['aF_sql_host'], $config['aF_sql_user'], $config['aF_sql_pass'], $config['aF_sql_data']);
    if(!self::$open) {
        die('<b>ERROR (/core/sql/1): Could not initialize database connection</b>');
    }

    self::$char = mysqli_set_charset(self::$open, $config['aF_sql_char']);
    if(!self::$char) {
        die('<br>ERROR (/core/sql/2): Could not set database charset</br>');
    }

    return self::$open;
}

public static function close() {
    self::$close = mysqli_close(self::$open);
    if(!self::$close) {
        die('<b>ERROR (/core/sql/3): Could not close database connection');
    }

    return TRUE;
}

mysqli_real_escape_string(aF_sql::$open, $_POST['username']);
```

That's it...